# Div overlap when width set to 100% but not when width set in pixel?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout for practice and there I set a wrapper Div and set the Width in CSS 100% and also its min-width:800px, but inside of this wrapper Div other content get overlapped when I resize the window. My html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />  
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>   
    <link href="~/Content/themes/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    </head>  
<body>  
    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div class="header">  
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:400px;margin:5px 0 0 100px">This is my site</div>  
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:500px;margin:5px 0 0 20px"><input type="text"/>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="button" value="Search"/>  </div>  
            <div style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 0 0 50px">@Html.Label("","LogIn","")&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp @Html.Label("SignIn")</div>  
        </div>  
    <div>@RenderBody()</div>  
        </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

My Css

```
body,html,div,form {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


#wrapper {
width:100%;
min-width:800px;
}

.header {
width:100%;
height:35px;
background-color:rosybrown;
}
```

So my problem is that if I set it in pixel then my header div is not expending on large screen and also the content of it will be hide on small screen. I'm completely out of idea's and Googled this problem but not got any solution.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? I don't know if what I got by copying your code is what you're actually getting.

Comment: @Paran0a okay I'll create that, but that will little different from this one as here I'm using ASP.Net MVC with HTML Helper for Label. Give me some time as my internet is very slow. :)

Comment: @Paran0a here you go https://jsfiddle.net/s5mnf45r/

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on following things to achieve this.

1. Remove inline CSS from DIV
2. Remove min-height, that is causing issue here
3. Create a class and give that `display:inline` and `margin` you want
4. If you want to give width, give that in percent only so that it will get adjusted

Try below

```css
body,html,div,form {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


#wrapper {
width:100%;
}

.header {
width:100%;
height:35px;
background-color:rosybrown;
}
.site {
  display:inline;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />  
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>   
    <link href="~/Content/themes/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    </head>  
<body>  
    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div class="header">  
            <div class='site'>This is my site</div>  
            <div class="site"><input type="text"/>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="button" value="Search"/>  </div>  
            <div style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 0 0 50px">Login</div>  
        </div>  
    <div>@RenderBody()</div>  
        </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Hope this helps to you!

Comment: Nope doesn't work at all for me. The problem is when we set the wrapper Div width in % it doesn't work but when we set in pixles it doesn't overlap, don't know what is causing.